# A question about groups generated by two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose a group $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ and $|G|<\infty$ where $|a|=m_0$  and $|b| = m$. How is it that the operation table for $G$ can be completely determined just by knowing $ab=b^na$ for some $n$?

I don't see how this is possible, but it says it is true in Fraleigh's introduction to abstract algebra book, but the does not have a proof.

I have played around a bit with looking at the coset $b\langle a \rangle$ but I am not guaranteed to get all the elements of G, so I look at another coset until you run out of non represented elements. Now I have partioned my group and I know every element must be of the form $a^kb^{k_0}$ or $b^ka^{k_0}$ but I don't see how knowing $ab=b^na$ helps defined the entire group.

Any help would be great.

Comment: If $b = 1$, then your condition says $a = a$. Something is off.

Comment: If you're also told the orders of $a$ and $b$, then this makes sense.

Comment: hmm it just says that if you know $ab=b^ka$ for some k, then the operation table is completely determined.

Comment: Consider what happens in the case that $n=1$, so your equation says the two generators commute. That's certainly not enough to determine the group completely; there are lots of non-isomorphic abelian groups that can be generated by two elements.  Not even the order of the group would be determined. As rghthndsd says, you also need the orders of the two generators.

Comment: ok say we know the order of the two generators. I think that is what the book is implying because it is constructing groups of 8 elements, and we are looking at a order 4 element and an order 2 element. ill edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording of the statement is slightly unclear. The way you state it, it sound as though you are told what $m$ and $m_0$ are, but not what $n$ is - only that $n$ exists. Without knowing $n$, you cannot possibly determine the multiplication table, so I will assume we are told what $n$ is. In that case, you can use the group relation $ab=ba^n$ to write all elements in the form $a^kb^l$, and so $|G| \le mm_0$. But there is still some uncertainty, because there could be more than one possible intersection of the subgroups $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$

To get more technical, we know that $G$ is a quotient group of the group $Z$ defined by the presentation $$Z=\langle x,y \mid x^{m_0}=y^m=1, xyx^{-1}=y^n\rangle.$$

Now $Y=\langle y \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $Z$ of order $m$ (we know it must be exctly $m$, because we are told that $|b|=m$), and $Z/Y$ is cyclic of order $m_0$. So $|Z|=mm_0$, but $G$ could still be a proper quotient of $Z$.

If we know $|G|$, then its isomorphism type is completely determined, which is equivalent to saying that its multiplication table is determined by the conditions. But if we are not told $|G|$, then there could be more than one possible order of groups satisfying theses conditions. For example, if $|a|=|b|=4$ and $ab=b^3a$, then $|Z|=16$, and $|G$| could have order $8$ or $16$. (The quaternion group $Q_8$ satisfies these conditions, but it has the additional relation $a^2=b^2$.)